# Constant values in .vtu files

Tags: constants, vtk, paraview

I am writing .vtu files from Fortran. The format I am using is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type= "UnstructuredGrid"  version= "0.1"  byte_order= "BigEndian">                         
 <UnstructuredGrid>                                                                                 
  <Piece NumberOfPoints="X" NumberOfCells="X">                                                
   <PointData Scalars="Pressure" Vectors="Velocity">                                                
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Pressures" format="ascii">
     etc.....
```

In the code above there are X points. Currently, if there is a DataArray, it must contain X values.

My question is - Suppose that you have a DataArray where every point has the same value (i.e. 1). Is there a way to write the file such that the value is written once yet applied to every point? I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest that this is possible. It seems to me that it is a waste of memory and computation to write out this value X times every time the file is written, especially if X is a very large number.

Or maybe the memory/cost requirements are negligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with point or cell data arrays.

You could instead write a field data array that has the single constant value. Field data arrays are not restricted to have the number of points/cells in the data set - think of them as a way to store meta data about a VTK data object.

It all depends on what you want to do with it, though. Do you need to color a geometry with it? Recent changes in VTK have made it possible to color by field data.

Comment: I have two unstructured files (times the number of timesteps). One will contain points where each point will have a velocity and position which will evolve with time. The other will contains points which have zero velocity and fixed positions. Is it sensible to declare the values of the first file with point arrays and the second with field arrays? Is the syntax for field data arrays the same as it is for points or cells, it seems it might be similar from [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/DataStorage)?

Comment: In this case, I don't think I would use a field array. Since the second unstructured mesh has constant points, couldn't you just have one mesh with those points for the whole time series and load the new timestep from the evolving series of files only? Also, if your velocity is zero, do you really need it in the array? Again, I'm not sure what you are intending with the data, so that's why I'm asking.